# Is there a MariaDB server package for Macos?

Tags: database

My team is switching from MySQL (which has downloadable packages for MacOS) to MariaDB and I'd like to switch on my Mac as well.

When going to [MariaDB's download page](https://mariadb.com/downloads), I only see packages for Windows and a few flavors of Linux. My first assumption was "okay, MariaDB doesn't offer packages for MacOS" but when searching, I was able to find this page which says that `.pkg` files are available: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-server-pkg-packages-on-macos/

But I wasn't able to actually locate a downloadable package, either in `.pkg` form or in `.tar.gz` form.

I see that it is available via *Homebrew* (which I'm using), but I was hoping to get an "official" package.

Comment: Have you contacted that company about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grr... I found out my problem. I had gone to MariaDB.*com* instead or MariaDB.*org*.

Downloading from https://downloads.mariadb.org/ has all the packages I was expecting except for the `.tar.gz` version for MacOS. I guess they only provide a `.pkg` file.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the latest (November 2018) release with an official macOS build here:

http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.1.37/macOS/

They do not provide macOS pkg builds for later versions such as 10.2, 10.3 or (alpha) 10.4.

Comment: Just realized I had the wrong site (duh). It's too bad they don't provide builds for MacOS anymore. Does everyone just use *Homebrew*, or does everyone use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)?

Comment: Mix of both. Homebrew is generally very popular.

Comment: I decided to mark my own answer as "correct", but up-vote yours.